# Alias to change directory is not working on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: command-line, bash, 15.04, alias

I wanted to create an alias to quickly go to a particular directory. I added the alias in `.bashrc` (I tried on `.bash_aliases` too, the same problem).

My alias is named `now`:

```
alias now='cd ~/talha_docs/code/github'
```

Now, my alias should be set to `now`. Then when I run `now` from command line I get the following message.

```
bash: /home/imox/talha_docs/code/github: Is a directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you source your .bashrc file

Comment: Yes, I did source .bashrc .

Comment: then it looks like there is another alias set to "now" try setting it to another alias such as NOW or something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is another alias set to `now` try setting it to another alias such as `NOW` or something else.

Answer (score 3):

Before we give an alias name, it would be a good idea to find out if the name  is already being used. To find out, we can use the type command.

For example let's try to create an alias named "test". So first let's test if the name is available.

```
type test
test is a shell builtin
```

Then the name "test" can't be used, and though you can be sure always what names you can use. Let's try "foo":

```
type foo
bash: type: foo: not found
```

This shows that "foo" is not used so i can used it for creating an alias.

Comment: When I try for now ( which was what I tried earlier ) :   `type now
bash: type: foo: not found`

Comment: What is the output of `type now`?

Comment: The output is  :

`bash: type: now: not found`

I guess it has to do something with shutdown as we use

`sudo shutdown now`

to shutdown. just a guess,

Comment: I don't think this a problem.. I already tested in my machine and runs normally.

Comment: you can check all aliases set before try the command `alias`. What is the output?

Comment: When i run `alias` there is no alias named now.